# Why Null Value is still in the column after dropping it PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am working with Python PySpark on Jupyter Notebook and I'm trying to remove any null values that in the column of "Age".

I tried this two methods and NONE of them works:

```
new_df.na.drop(subset=["Age"])
```

```
new_df.dropna()
```

Here's my code that I am working with at the moment:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

new_df = new_df.withColumn(
  "Age",
  f.when(
    (f.col("Age") >= 0) & 
    (f.col("Age") <= 95), f.col("Age")).otherwise(f.lit(None))
)

new_df.dropna()
new_df.select('Age').distinct().show(1000, False)
```

I am not sure what I did wrong or where is the error coming that null values are not being removed, please advise on what I can fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `new_df = new_df.dropna()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the new_df.dropna() to new ref.
`dropna()` process the incoming dataframe and outputs the new processed dataframe. It's not the in-place operation. Therefore, modify your code as below-

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

new_df = new_df.withColumn(
  "Age",
  f.when(
    (f.col("Age") >= 0) & 
    (f.col("Age") <= 95), f.col("Age")).otherwise(f.lit(None))
)

na_df = new_df.dropna()
na_df.select('Age').distinct().show(1000, False)
```

Please note-

```
na_df = new_df.dropna()
```

ref - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=na#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.na

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly and thank you for the documentation. Just started learning about PySpark and a lot of things are not similar to Pandas.